# Sending Data Driven Subscription to One email that has many parameter combinations

Tags: email, ssrs-2008-r2, data-driven

I have a sales report that is sent to every store on a schedule it has parameter store id and store key and is sent to store managers for their store. The problem is there are emails in the list for district managers and such that will have many store id and store keys assigned to them. 
will the subscription send the district manager one email per store combo or just pick one and send for the one store?

```
   select * from salestbl
   where storeid = @ storeid
   and storekey = @storekey
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each district manager should receive one email per store, assuming there are no problems with the DDS.